# Geographically limited / gradual release process

Tags: agile, release

I am looking for more information on a **gradual release process** - that is when you release new version of a software only to certain set of end users, mostly geographically limited (or limited by a reach of particular server).

Google seems to be blind to this term - that indicates that's not how it's called. What's the name then?

EDIT: An example of what I mean is when Facebook rolled out new image galleries they were first visible to certain users only, then to whole US and then to the rest of the world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, take a look at: [Software Engineering (Ian Sommerville)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321313798) 8th.

Take a look at chapters 17 and 23. They'll give you an overview on how to release software for groups (testers and users).

More info about release planning: http://jamesshore.com/Agile-Book/release_planning.html

The technique name **`Beta Testing`** is commonly used: Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_testing#Beta_testing

> Beta testing comes after alpha testing and can be considered a form of external user acceptance testing. Versions of the software, known as beta versions, are released to a limited audience outside of the programming team. The software is released to groups of people so that further testing can ensure the product has few faults or bugs. Sometimes, beta versions are made available to the open public to increase the feedback  field to a maximal number of future users

You may also want to look into Software Prototyping.

Comment: Can you expand on this answer. As it stands it's not particularly useful or informative.

Comment: I meant read the book, but I'll be more specific.

Comment: Amazon link to 8th edition added.

Comment: @JBRWilkinson that's the book :D. @daniel.sedlacek just take a look at these chapters they'll help you to understand more about this type of release, and also don't forget to check James Shore's link.

Comment: Many thanks but isn't there any online resource? Actually what is the accepted term for "releasing software for groups"? Is it the "gradual release process"? thx

Comment: You may want to take a deep look at prototyping. This technique, also aborded in this book (chp 17), is intended for small releases and previewing. About "any online resource" you could try to find it online, but it'll be piracy. Buy the book, if you work with software, as it seems, this book is going to be of GREAT help for you.

Comment: @daniel.sedlacek take a look at my edited answer. I answered about the name.